# Unable to install nvidia dali in Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, nvidia, dali

I am not able to install the Nvidia dali module in windows 10.
Inside anaconda I am executing the following command:
`pip install nvidia-dali`

and it is producing the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bsx79qn9\\nvidia-dali\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bsx79qn9\\nvidia-dali\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bsx79qn9\nvidia-dali\pip-egg-info'
cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bsx79qn9\nvidia-dali\
Complete output (18 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bsx79qn9\nvidia-dali\setup.py", line 150, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
RuntimeError:
###########################################################################################
The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

This package can be installed as:
$ pip install nvidia-pyindex
$ pip install nvidia-dali

Please refer to NVIDIA DALI installation guide for instructions:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/installation.html
###########################################################################################
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

In the above error it is suggesting to visit the URL:
`https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/installation.html`

I am also following the instructions given in the URL but still, I am unable to install it.

Can anyone please suggest to me the correct way of installing Nvidia dali in a windows environment.

Answer (score 3):

Nvidia dali is not supported in Windows: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DALI/issues/476#issuecomment-724551468

When you try to install you end up installing placeholder package from pipy